# python define object with same name

Tags: python

I am not sure why the outcome is this one for the following example, and explanation on what is happening is appreciated!

Define the following class in Python:

```
class Person:
    population = 0
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print ('Initializing %s' % self. name)
        
        Person.population += 1
        
    def __del__(self):
        print  ('%s says bye' % self.name)
        
        Person.population -= 1
        
        if Person.population == 0:
            print ('I am the last one')
        else:
            print ('there are still %d people left' % Person.population)
        
    def sayHi(self):
        print ("Hi, my name is %s" % self.name)
        
    def howMany(self):
        print ('We have %d persons here' % Person.population)
```

When I do the following for the first time

```
p1 = Person('p1')
```

I got

```
Initializing p1
```

This makes sense,

but if I call this again

```
p1 = Person('p1')
```

I got the following that I don't understand

```
Initializing p1
p1 says bye
there are still 1 people left
```

If I call this

```
p1 = Person('p2')
```

I have

```
Initializing p2
```

and I have 2 persons by call

```
p1.howMany()
```

I am not sure what is happening.

Comment: ``0+1+1-1 = 1`` - or what do you not understand about your output?

Comment: This, does It mean that in Python, if I define an object with same name, I am creating and deleting that object again, so that I will also have 'p1 says bye'?

Comment: It's a little more complex than that, but here's the basics: ``p1 = Person('p1')`` creates and object and ``p1`` holds a reference to the object. When later you assign something different to ``p1`` (even if it's another instance of the same class) then there are no more references to the first object and it will be garbage collected by Python. You could also write ``p1=None`` to decrement the object's reference counter - the point is that once the reference counter reaches zero the obejct will be garbage collected and your ``__del__`` method will be called.

Comment: And calling ``Person('p1')`` will create a different object each time, even if you pass it the same name. You can check it with ``id(object)`` - e.g. ``id(p1)`` or ``id(self)`` when within the methods. Note however, that Python may decide to recycle the same object id immediately.